# How to make this code work in a Wordpress

Tags: html, wordpress

Here is the code:

```
a:4:{i:2;a:3:{s:5:"title";s:78:"[:lt]naujas numeris[:en]
latest publication";s:4:"text";s:212:"<a 
href="http://www.example.com/p/post-post/" target="_blank"><img 
src="http://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/200x300.jpg" 
height="254" width="165"></a>";s:6:"filter";b:0;}i:3;a:3:{s:5:"title";
s:78:"[:lt]Naujausias numeris[:en]latest 
publication";s:4:"text";s:212:"<a href="http://www.example/post/" 
target="_blank"><img src="http://www.example.jpg" height="254" width="165"></a>";s:6:"filter";
b:0;}i:4;a:3:{s:5:"title";s:68:"[:lt]ATSARGIAI:
[:en]CAREFUL:";s:4:"text";s:809:"<div id="widgettext">
/div>
<table>
        TABLE
</table>
<div id="tarpelis"></div>
<div id="rudalinija"></div>
<div id="tarpelis"></div>
<div id="tarpelis"></div>";s:6:"filter";b:0;}s:12:"_multiwidget";i:1;}
```

This piece of code is a record in a website wp_options DB table (optopn_name: widget_text). I had to change one element of the code (TABLE), but right after that some problems occured (like previous table dissapeared). I fixed back the code, but looks like whenever i change name of the person in this table it dissapears on the website.

```
<tr>
<td><!--:lt-->Name Surname<!--:--><!--:ru-->Name Surname<!--:--></td> 
</tr>
```

Do you have an idea why could this happen?

Also that code a:4:{i:2... is a bit troubling me, can you explain me what that does? It may be the case.

Comment: That is PHP’s `serialize` format. And you should not edit data in that format manually - that is very likely to mess up the format.

Answer (score 0):

This is a compressed, minimized version of the original javascript or markup or other code that had the names of functions and variables changed to make things as small as possible. You can spend time looking through it to find it all but it can take a while.

Answer (score 0):

Somehow missed that, but solution was quite easy. Turns out the only way to change it was to go to appearance(widgets) where i found this table. Eventhrough it is still strange that changing data in the database (where is stored that post with table) resulting to invalid post. Still thank you for your suggestions :)